Trying to derive my cost function's Hessian. Obtained Jacobians linking the gradient to the parameter vector. How can I combine the Jacobians?
I have a cost function $\mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X})$ defined with respect to some parameter matrix $\mathbf{X}$, which in vectorized form is some $V$-dimensional vector, i.e., vec($\mathbf{X}$) $\in \mathbb{R}^V$.
Knowing how the function $\mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X})$ is related to $\mathbf{X}$ via specific operations (e.g., some quantities $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, etc.), I was able to derive the gradient of $\mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X})$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{X}$, i.e., $\frac{\partial \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{V}$, by obtaining the Jacobian of these operations, and then collapsing the Jacobians. E.g.:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X})} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{X}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A}) } \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B}) } \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{C}) } ... \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{V}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{W}) } \frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{W}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{X}) }
\end{align*}
These tend to be simple operations, e.g., if $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{B}$ for some constant matrix $\mathbf{Q}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\mathbf{Q}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times r}$, and $\mathbf{B}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n}$, then the Jacobian between $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is given by $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B}) }$ $=$ $\big( \mathbf{I}_n \bigotimes \mathbf{Q} \big)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{mn \times rn}$. This chain of Jacobians is composed of "simple Jacobians" like this, which may be simple Kronecker products (like this last example with $\frac{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{A}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{B}) }$), commutation matrices, diagonal matrices, etc.
Now I am interested in deriving the Hessian of $\mathcal{f}(\mathbf{x})$, and believe the best way to do so is to relate my gradient $\frac{\partial \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{x}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{x})}$ back to $\mathbf{x}$ once again by specific operations, taking the simple Jacobians of each of these operations, and then collapsing them together. Then I can obtain the Jacobian of $\frac{\partial \mathcal{f}(\mathbf{x}) }{\partial \text{vec}(\mathbf{x})}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, and that matrix $\mathbf{H}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{V \times V}$ should represent the Hessian of my function.
I find that the gradient is easy to derive by collapsing vectors with matrices (e.g., the mixed Kronecker matrix-vector product has nice ways of collapsing Jacobian terms, typically manifest as Kronecker products, onto a vector: ($\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{B}$) vec$(\mathbf{V})$ = vec($\mathbf{B} \mathbf{V} \mathbf{A}^\top$), or vec$(\mathbf{V})^\top$ ($\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{B}$) = vec($\mathbf{B}^\top \mathbf{V} \mathbf{A}$), which make it easy to collapse Jacobians together).
However, I am finding that deriving the Hessian is much harder. I'm not sure if I am doing it the right way, or the way people typically derive the Hessian from products of Jacobians.
For instance, I am trying to collapse this single term in the Hessian, which is a product of 7 total Jacobians:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{H}_1 = \underbrace{ \bigg( \mathbf{e}_k^\top \bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{V} \bigg) }_{\mathbb{R}^{ V \times V D }} \ \underbrace{ \mathbf{K}^{(D,V)} }_{\mathbb{R}^{ V D \times V D }} \ \underbrace{ \bigg( \mathbf{L} \bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{D} \bigg)}_{\mathbb{R}^{ V D \times D N}} \ \underbrace{ \text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \Big( \mathbf{U} \Big) \bigg) }_{\mathbb{R}^{ D N \times D N}} \ \underbrace{ \bigg( \mathbf{L}^\top \bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{D} \bigg) }_{\mathbb{R}^{ D N \times V D}} \ \underbrace{ \mathbf{K}^{(V,D)} }_{\mathbb{R}^{ V D \times V D }} \ \underbrace{ \bigg( \mathbf{e}_k \bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{V} \bigg) }_{\mathbb{R}^{ V D \times V }}
\end{align*}
in this expression:

$\mathbf{L}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{V \times N}$ and $\mathbf{U}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{D \times N}$.

$\text{diag} \bigg( \text{vec} \Big( \mathbf{U} \Big) \bigg)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{DN \times DN}$ is formed by vectorizing $\mathbf{U}$, then forming a diagonal matrix from that vectorization.

$\mathbf{e}_k$ $\in \mathbb{R}^D$ is the $k$th standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^D$.

$\mathbf{K}^{(V,D)}$ and $\mathbf{K}^{(D,V)}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{VD \times VD}$ each represent different versions of the commutation matrix ($\mathbf{K}^{(V,D)} = {\mathbf{K}^{(D,V)}}^\top$).

$\mathbf{I}_D$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{D \times D}$ is the $D$-dimensional identity matrix.


I need to collapse these matrices together into forming a compact analytic expression of $\mathbf{H}_1$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{V \times V}$.
I know how to collapse two Kronecker products together, e.g. $(\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{C} \bigotimes \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{AC} \bigotimes \mathbf{BD})$ as noted here, and how to apply commutation matrices to certain Kronecker products, e.g. $\mathbf{K}^{(r,m)} (\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{B}) \mathbf{K}^{(n,q)} = (\mathbf{B} \bigotimes \mathbf{A})$ when $\mathbf{A}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{r \times q}$ as noted here. However, I don't see a way how to collapse these terms together with the diagonal term in the middle.
I have a few questions:

does anyone know of any recourses, e.g. a textbook resource sort of like the "matrix cookbook", that give someone all the pieces they need to know how to collapse Jacobian pieces together? When I say \textit{pieces}, I mean things like commutation matrices, Kronecker products, etc.

does anyone see any way for me to collapse all Jacobian quantities together to have a nice analytic expression for $\mathbf{H}_1$? My main issue is resolving the commutation matrices, and I don't know how to "remove" them from the product of Jacobians.



I looked up on google "commutation matrix sandwiched between two kronecker products", and Gemini suggested that $(\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{B}) \mathbf{K} (\mathbf{I} \bigotimes \mathbf{C})$ can be simplfied into becoming $(\mathbf{A} \bigotimes \mathbf{C}) \mathbf{B}$ with respect to a commutation matrix $\mathbf{K}$ with appropriate dimension. Can I use that here to "remove" the commutation matrices? I feel like I could have a nice analytic expression for $\mathbf{H}_1$ if I could just remove the commutation matrices...

It would be nice (or necessary) that you describe how $f$ relates to $a, b\dots$ and how those relate to $x$.

Are you asking how to compute the Hessian of a composite function  of say the form $y=f(a(b(c(x)))$?  If so, this can be done quickly by replacing each component function with its quadratic Taylor polynomial, then composing all those quadratic functions.

If $\bf x$ is a vector why do you use the ${\rm vec}$ operator?!?

"Now I am interested in deriving the Hessian of $f(\mathbf x)$, and believe the best way to do so is to..." Is there a reason you cannot show the specific cost function?

Hi mathcounterexamples.net, I provided a bit more information in the body of my post, but I feel like giving specific information for how f relates to different quantities ($\mathbf{A}$,$\mathbf{B}$, etc.) will actually divert from my question. I am more interesting in how when people solve Jacobian operations like this one, how can I collapse a long chain like I wrote above for $\mathbf{H}_1$. I'd like to use tricks to get rid of the commutation matrices, if possible.

Nicholas, I apologize, but the specific cost function is something that is confidential to my work and I cannot explain it here. I can only ask specific technical questions, such as how to collapse specific terms (kronecker products with commutation matrices).

Hi Ted, I specified $\mathbf{X}$ now as a matrix for a more general setting.  I am writing the Jacobians of vectorization of one matrix quantity with respect to vectorization of another matrix quantity.

I understand that you can't reveal the precise maps you're dealing with for confidentiality reasons. However, it could help to tell why you're trying to collapse those terms. Is it for math purposes or computation efficiencies? One comment suggests that you may be dealing with neural networks. If that is the case, using forward and backward propagation of the Hessian based on the chain rule (and automated differentiation?) may be a way to tackle your problem. It's easier to write than to do it, though...

$
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\Hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\rr#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gg#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\bb#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\rr{\LR{#1}}}
\def\BLR#1{\bb{\LR{#1}}}
\def\GLR#1{\gg{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\hessLR#1#2#3{\LR{\hess{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\def\HessLR#1#2{\LR{\Hess{#1}{#2}}}
$Let's use a lowercase letter denote the vectorization of a matrix of the same name, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
a = \vc A,\q b = \vc B,\q c = \vc C,\q x = \vc X \\
}$$
And we don't need a chain of 24 variables to recognize the pattern. The 4 variables above will be sufficient.
Calculate the differential of the cost function.
Then sequentially substitute each new variable
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= \gradLR fa \cdot \rr{da} \\
 &= \gradLR fa \cdot \rr{\BR{\gradLR ab db}} \\
 &= \BR{\gradLR a{b}^T\gradLR fa} \cdot \gg{db} \\
 &= \BR{\gradLR a{b}^T\gradLR fa} \cdot \gg{\BR{\gradLR bc dc}} \\
 &= \BR{\gradLR b{c}^T\gradLR a{b}^T\gradLR fa} \cdot {dc} \\
 &= \BR{\gradLR c{x}^T\gradLR b{c}^T\gradLR a{b}^T\gradLR fa} \cdot {dx} \\
}$$
From this differential expression, we identify the gradient vector as
$$\eqalign{
\grad fx = \gradLR c{x}^T\gradLR b{c}^T\gradLR a{b}^T\gradLR fa
\:\equiv\: g
\\\\
}$$

We need to switch to index notation for the remaining steps
$$\eqalign{
g_\ell &=
  \gradLR{c_k}{x_\ell} \gradLR{b_j}{c_k}
  \gradLR{a_i}{b_j} \gradLR{f}{a_i}
}$$
Since the Hessian is the gradient of the gradient, we have
$$\eqalign{
dg_\ell &= H_{\ell m}\,dx_m \\
 &= \grad{}{x_m}\BR{\gradLR{c_k}{x_\ell} \gradLR{b_j}{c_k}
    \gradLR{a_i}{b_j} \gradLR{f}{a_i}} dx_m \\
}$$
From this expression, we deduce that the Hessian has the following components
$$\eqalign{
H_{\ell m} = H_{m\ell} =
 \gg{\hessLR{c_k}{x_\ell}{x_m}}
 \gradLR{b_j}{c_k} \gradLR{a_i}{b_j} \gradLR{f}{a_i}
}$$
The main difficulty is that the term in $\gg{\rm green}$ is a third-order tensor, which doesn't have a nice representation in standard matrix-vector notation.
Since we must use index notation, we might as well revert to the original matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
{\large\cal H}_{\ell r ms} &=
{\large\cal H}_{ms \ell r} &=
 \hessLR{C_{kq}}{X_{\ell r}}{X_{ms}}
 \gradLR{B_{jp}}{C_{kq}} 
 \gradLR{A_{in}}{B_{jp}}
 \gradLR{f}{A_{in}}
}$$
This "Hessian" is a fourth-order tensor.

Does this mean that in this example we cannot write the Hessian as $\partial^2 f/\partial ({\rm vec}{\pmb X})\partial ({\rm vec}{\pmb X})^\top$?

That is, of course, a correct expression for the Hessian. The difficulty is to express it in terms of the intermediate $\lbrace A,B,C,\ldots\rbrace$ variables.  I assume that those variables represent the layers in some kind of neural network.
